# Does Google artifact registry support generic package format?

Tags: google-artifact-registry

Jfrog artifactory supports a repository, where in we can save an artifact of any generic type i.e. of any file extension.  Does google artifact registry also support such kind of repository creation?

Answer (score 0):

Artifact Repository doesn't support generic repositories, but you could use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) buckets for this instead.